# Getting the current page in TestComplete

Tags: jscript, testcomplete

I am writing a Script for TestComplete using JScript.
According to the documentation I can get the current page using the line:

```
page = browser.Page("*");
```

But instead I get a message: waiting for "*" and after that an error that the page "*" was not found.
Maybe I got something wrong there. What I am looking for is a method that gives me the Page Object for the current page I am on. Can anyone help me and tell me if such a method exists.
I want to avoid using NameMapping because in there the objects are fixed in their containers. In the project I test these containers may change so I use xpath recognition all the way through.

Comment: Which browser version and TestComplete version? Do you have the latest browser support patches installed?

Comment: I use Firefox and TC 11. I don't think I have any patches installed.

Comment: [TestComplete Firefox patches](http://support.smartbear.com/downloads/testcomplete/firefox-patches/) page says you need TestComplete 11.11 or 11.10 to work with Firefox 41.

Comment: thanks a lot, I will check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you specified should work if:

1. The **browser** variable contains a reference to a specific browser (e.g. *Sys.Browser("firefox")*).
2. The **browser** variable is the current browser (*Sys.Browser()*) and the current browser is set. The current browser is set when you call the Run or Navigate method of a browser object (e.g. *Browsers.Item("firefox").Run();*).
3. You have a page opened in the current browser.
4. The browser version is supported. Make sure that you have the latest version of TestComplete (11.11 by the moment) to be sure that your browser is supported.

Comment: I think I fail option 4. I have decided to do further test setups with IE since everything works (for once) fine in IE.